# Slight mismatch with R rasterization process

Tags: r, projection, raster

I'm working on a large project that involves creating a node-and-link network between cities and then gridding that data onto a preset grid. I've used the R raster library for this process.

Currently, the rasterized data do not quite match up with where I expect them to be (i.e. the grid cells that are supposed to cover cities don't match up with exactly where the cities actually are).

[image: cities]

The dark red grid cells are supposed to be on top of the black dots, but they all seem to be shifted one grid cell to the west.

I suspect that there is something I'm missing in terms of the projection and the 'crs' option in the raster library, but I'm having trouble figuring out what I did wrong, and how to fix it.

Update: I don't think I can pick out a single chunk of code that gets at the problem, but my raster process looks like this:

```
rasterize(SpLin, fine.raster, field=*a number*, crs="proj=longlat", background=0)
```

And the image came from this (slightly trimmed):

```
pC <- ggplot(aes(x=long, y=lat, fill=value), data=dat_grid) + # dat_grid is the rasterized data
geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high="red") +
geom_polygon(data=maine_state,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),colour="grey",fill="white",alpha=0) + 
... (trimmed)
geom_point(data=points.df,aes(long,lat),size=2) # the black dots marking the cities
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't know a lot about R myself, but it would help us out a lot if you could include a relevant [snippet of code](http://sscce.org/) that generates this map.

Comment: Updated the post with what I think is the problem code. Thanks, @Hannele

Comment: try using this string as your CRS... "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

Comment: @miles2know, I changed the CRS to your string  (`crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"`) and it didn't influence the output at all (i.e. the output is exactly the same).

Comment: Is it possible to share the data used in this exercise?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, not really. The rasterization is in the middle of a long process. But the locations of the black dots in the figure is the same in the rasterization process. I'm wondering if it's some issue with the grid cells since they are set from an existing, non-uniform grid. Perhaps I've mismatched the center of the grid cells with the boundaries of the grid cells...